# Accessing an element that has currently been scrolled to in jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to be able to set scroll points via jQuery so that when a user scrolls to the top of a section on the page a function triggers. I have done this in the following way:-

```
var target = $("section").offset().top;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= target) {
        alert("test");
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 250);
```

This works however where I have alert("test") I want to be able to access the element that has currently been scrolled to so that I can get data from it's html i.e. if a user scrolls to the top of #section2 I can access it at that point and progress from there because different sections need to fire different functions. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to set up a [scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event delegate at somewhere high up (e.g. window, document, body) and see if the event gives you information about the element that was scrolled?

Comment: I think I now realise why it wasn't working. As ozk stated it seems it is only getting the very first section element. What I may do is initially get all of the top position's of every section element and put them into an array and then each time the user scrolls it will check against this array to see if they have reached any of these point and fire the relevant function if so.

Answer (score 0):

you element is essentially the first of `$("section")`. The `offset()` method in jQuery returns the offset of the first matching element only. [from the docs](http://api.jquery.com/offset/):

> Get the current coordinates **of the first element**, or set the coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.